# putty network error when running python scripts on raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, python, android, putty, raspberry-pi

I run python scripts on my raspberry pi from my android device and it always works for 3 or 4 times, but when I do it more, putty tells me the following:

```
Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

(During this 3-5 tryings I watch putty and enter basic commands in putty to check if my laptop is still connected to the pi)

How can I debug this? Is there a problem in my python script on my rasberry pi, in the android app or with some kind of network issue?

Thanks

Comment: What scripts are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a keepalive value in PuTTY, if the software you are using on the Android device supports the same options as the Windows version of PuTTY. Load the session, then click on **Connection** under **Category** and set the keepalive option to a few seconds, e.g., 5, to lessen the chance of the connection being dropped. You will need to click on **Session** to save the new setting. Then log into the SSH server.

[image: PuTTY keepalives]

You could also check the SSH server logs for any messages that might be logged when the problem occurs and even turn on logging in PuTTY - see the image below - though I'm not sure if anything might appear there that you could use to help isolate the cause of the problem.

[image: PuTTY Logging]

In one case when I received that message repeatedly while using PuTTY to connect to a particular server, I was able to resolve the problem by simply restarting the SSH server software at the server end, though the SSH server software was running on a Microsoft Windows system in that case.

You could also try another SSH client program on the Android device, e.g., [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en), to see if the problem is independent of the SSH client software.

Another option for debugging is to install [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on the Rasberry Pi or use [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) on the Rasbery Pi to capture the SSH traffic to a file and then transfer that file to another system where you could analyze it with Wireshark - you could [set a filter in Wireshark](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/tools/sniffing/wireshark/capfilter/#portnum) to view only the SSH traffic using a filter of `tcp.port==22`. You would need to look for anything unexpected, such as a RST packet coming from the server to reset the connection, a lot of packet retransmissions, etc.